# ruby Thread#allocate TypeError

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I was looking in detail at the Thread class. Basically, I was looking for an elegant mechanism to allow thread-local variables to be inherited as threads are created. For example the functionality I am looking to create would ensure that

```
Thread.new do
   self[:foo]="bar"
   t1=Thread.new { puts self[:foo] }
end
```

=> "bar"

i.e. a Thread would inherit it's calling thread's thread-local variables

So I hit upon the idea of redefining Thread.new, so that I could add an extra step to copy the thread-local variables into the new thread from the current thread. Something like this:

```
class Thread
  def self.another_new(*args)
    o=allocate
    o.send(:initialize, *args)
    Thread.current.keys.each{ |k| o[k]=Thread.current[k] }
    o
  end
end
```

But when I try this I get the following error:

```
:in `allocate': allocator undefined for Thread (TypeError)
```

I thought that as Thread is a subclass of Object, it should have a working #allocate method. Is this not the case?

Does anyone have any deep insight on this, and on how to achieve the functionality I am looking for.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread.new do
  Thread.current[:foo]="bar"
    t1=Thread.new(Thread.current) do |parent|
    puts parent[:foo] ? parent[:foo] : 'nothing'
  end.join
end.join 

#=> bar
```

**UPDATED:**

Try this in irb:

## thread_ext.rb

```
class Thread
  def self.another_new(*args)
    parent = Thread.current
    a = Thread.new(parent) do |parent|
      parent.keys.each{ |k| Thread.current[k] = parent[k] }
      yield
    end
    a
  end
end
```

## use_case.rb

```
A = Thread.new do
  Thread.current[:local_a]="A"
  B1 =Thread.another_new do
    C1 = Thread.another_new{p Thread.current[:local_a] }.join
  end

  B2 =Thread.another_new do
    C2 = Thread.another_new{p Thread.current[:local_a] }.join
  end

  [B1, B2].each{|b| b.join }
end.join
```

## output

```
"A"
"A"
```

Comment: I thought about this sort of explicit approach, but I was hoping to find something more elegant - so that I could overwrite the Thread constructor to copy the thread-local variables into the child Thread as it was created... which lead me to finding that Thread#allocate throws a hissy-fit!

Comment: @SteveGooberman-Hill What actually you wonna to do in your application? Lets discuss!

Comment: Actually I am trying to refactor some existing code each to make it neater and more elegant, and more orthogonal. What I am trying to avoid is deeply nesting objects. If object A (a thread) contains many Bs  each of which contains many C's. C needs to spin off new Threads, which need parameters from A. Making each C contain it's parent B as an attribute, which contains its parent A as an attribute strikes me as really kludgy. So the plan is that A should set some thread-local variables, which can then be inherited by any new Threads created by C.

Comment: Think of A as an interface to a device, which runs in it's own Thread. C (several layers of nesting down) is an alarm condition handler, which spins off a Thread to raise the alarm to a remote server. So C needs some basic data from A. Nesting parents as attributes strikes me as inelegant :-)

Comment: @SteveGooberman-Hill Check out updated version. May be it is stable, need to test.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking along much the same lines. Your code is nice as it avoids the obvious race condition trap by passing the parent and using a yield. I've made a small modification to ensure that any remaining arguments are passed by the yield statement. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @SteveGooberman-Hill your welcome! p.s. do you cover this with any rspec tests?

Comment: @Steve Gooberman-Hill better write another answer, crediting the inspirational one, than modifying an existing one.

Comment: @CodeGroover I'll write some unit tests to cover this. This code will go in the next major release of an embedded app that goes in remote places where availability is key. So tests are on their way! Thansk for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised answer based on @CodeGroover's suggestion, with a simple unit test harness

## ext/thread.rb

```
class Thread
  def self.inherit(*args, &block)
    parent = Thread.current
    t = Thread.new(parent, *args) do |parent|
      parent.keys.each{ |k| Thread.current[k] = parent[k] }
      yield *args
    end
    t
  end
end
```

## test/thread.rb

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'ext/thread'

class ThreadTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_inherit
    Thread.current[:foo]=1
    m=Mutex.new
    
    #check basic inheritence
    t1= Thread.inherit do 
      assert_equal(1, Thread.current[:foo])
    end
      
    #check inheritence with parameters - in this case a mutex
    t2= Thread.inherit(m) do |m|
      assert_not_nil(m)
      m.synchronize{ Thread.current[:bar]=2 }
             
      assert_equal(1, Thread.current[:foo])
      assert_equal(2, Thread.current[:bar])
      
      sleep 0.1 
    end
      
    #ensure t2 runs its mutexs-synchronized block first
    sleep 0.05
    
    #check that the inheritence works downwards only - not back up in reverse
    m.synchronize do
      assert_nil(Thread.current[:bar])
    end
    
    [t1,t2].each{|x| x.join }
        
  end
  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing recently and was able to come up with the following answer. Note I am aware the following is a hack and not recommended, but for the sake of answering the specific question on how you could alter the `Thread.new` functionality, I have done as following:

```rb
class Thread
  class << self
    alias :original_new :new

    def new(*args, **options, &block)
      original_thread = Thread.current
      instance = original_new(*args, **options, &block)
      original_thread.keys.each do |key|
        instance[key] = original_thread[key]
      end
      instance
    end
  end
end
```